# ReferenceError: YouTube is not defined / YouTube API

Tags: javascript, express, google-api, youtube-api, pug

I have the following code, attempting to do a search with the `YouTube Data API`. I am using an `express generated stack` with `jade`.

```
#player

    script.
        // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
        //    after the API code downloads.
        var player;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '345',
                width: '540',
                videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
        //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
        //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
        var done = false;
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                done = true;
            }
        }

        function stopVideo() {
            player.stopVideo();
        }

        function googleApiClientReady() {
            gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyCgOmTzCI4-gkUhL4hOm9R6I9tmUlVqtCw');
            gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
                /**
                * This function searches for videos related to the keyword 'dogs'. The video IDs and titles
                * of the search results are logged to Apps Script's log.
                *
                * Note that this sample limits the results to 25. To return more results, pass
                * additional parameters as documented here:
                *   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list
                */
                function searchByKeyword() {
                    var results = YouTube.Search.list('id,snippet', {q: 'dogs', maxResults: 25});
                    for(var i in results.items) {
                        var item = results.items[i];
                        console.log('[%s] Title: %s', item.id.videoId, item.snippet.title);
                    }
                }

                searchByKeyword();
            });
        }

    script(src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady")`
```

According to my code I believe that it should load a video (and it does), and then do a search for 'dogs', and log the results to the console.

However, I receive the error:

`ReferenceError: YouTube is not defined`

I have no idea what I am doing wrong...something with the script not being loaded maybe...but I have tried loading the script in all of the places it could go, I think.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I placed the `script(` at the bottom again - as in my original code...and now I can confirm that the `searchByKeyword` method is being run...but the problem is back to the `YouTube is not defined` problem. In the following block, the first line is from my console.log message that I put at the beginning of the `searchByKeyword` method, and the second line is the same error (the title of this post):

`searchByKeyword is running 
ReferenceError: YouTube is not defined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial problem is that when `gapi.client` loads it extends the base `gapi` Object. To access the Youtube api you use `gapi.client.youtube.search`instead of `Youtube.Search`.

Also Javascript is inherently asynchronous so the return of any XHR request must be in a callback or promisified.

```
function searchByKeyword() {
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
    q: 'dogs',
    part: 'snippet'
  });

  request.execute(function(results) {
    for(var i in results.items) {
      var item = results.items[i];
      console.log('[%s] Title: %s', item.id.videoId,item.snippet.title);
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: can you explain what is going on with the `function(results)`? I know that I have understood it before, just a little hazy/rusty at the moment.

Comment: Basically without going into heaps of detail... `request.execute` is a function that accepts a function (generally referred to as a callback) as its first argument when the XHR returns it calls your function and puts the results of the request as the first argument. It is a pattern that is used a lot. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: thanks - its all coming back to me now haha...no heaps of detail necessary.